# Configuration of ajax header and redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, header, request

I have simple node auth app.
What i want to do is to send token in header with redirect to url.
For example user click on profile and it redirects him with token so he can access that page.

I am trying what i found but it make something weird what i odnt understand.
After click on url it makes 2 request. And only the first one is with jwt bearer token header. And second one which redirects is without. I added image for better understanding.
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfT6L.png)

And here is code of my layout.handlebars

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>LoginApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO"
        crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header clearfix">
            <nav>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
                   // HERE I CLICK ON PROFILE
                    <li role="presentation"><a onclick="submitForm()">Profil</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation"><a href="/users/register">Register</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <h3 class="text-muted">LoginApp</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2015 LoginApp, Inc.</p>
    </footer>

    </div> <!-- /container -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        function submitForm() {
            var data = {};//Your JSON Data
            console.log("ok");
            var headers = {
                "Contect-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Bearer " + token
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/profile',
                type: 'GET',//'GET','PUT','DELETE'
                headers: headers,
                data: data,
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('error ', error);
                }

            });
            window.location = "http://localhost:3000/users/profile";
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

And part of my route.js

```
// Login view
router.get("/login", function (req, res) {
  res.render("login");
});

// Login
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;

  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        msg: "User not found"
      });
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign({
            data: user
          },
          config.secret, {
            expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
          }
        );

        res.render("index", {
          token: token
        });

      } else {
        return res.json({
          success: false,
          msg: "Wrong password"
        });
      }
    });
  });
});

// Profile
router.get(
  "/profile",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", {
    session: false
  }),
  (req, res, next) => {
    res.json({
      user: req.user
    });
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't redirect with custom headers. Try to use local storage, cookies, GET or POST variables, depending on your backend implementation. Below is an example of storing token in the local storage:

```
// Container for the frontend functions
app = {};

app.config = {
    'sessionToken': false
};

// Set the session token in the app.config object as well as localstorage
app.setSessionToken = function(token) {
    app.config.sessionToken = token;
    var tokenString = JSON.stringify(token);
    localStorage.setItem('token', tokenString);
};

// Get the session token from localstorage and set it in the app.config object
app.getSessionToken = function() {
    var tokenString = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if(typeof(tokenString) == 'string') {
        try {
            var token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
            app.config.sessionToken = token;
        } catch(e) {
            app.config.sessionToken = false;
        }
    }
};

// Get the token from the local after the window loads
window.onload = function() {
    app.getSessionToken();
};
```

More info: https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens